# PHP email sending with pdf attachment

Tags: php

Trying to send an email with pdf attachment, tried using swiftmailer and that did not work, this code worked with a zip but not PDF :(

```
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)));
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<?php echo $message."<br /><br />";
?>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 


Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="<?php echo $filename?>"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<?php echo $filename?>" 

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php 
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
$message = ob_get_clean(); 
//send the email 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Mails gets sent fine and I get the mail: but the attachment is not there and in the meial has all the base64 encoded in the email like:

ontent-Type: application/octet-stream; name="media.pdf" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="media.pdf" JVBERi0xLjMKMSAwIG9iago8PCAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwovT3V0bGluZXMgMiAwIFIKL1BhZ2Vz IDMgMCBSID4+CmVuZG9iagoyIDAgb2JqCjw8IC9UeXBlIC9PdXRsaW5lcyAvQ291bnQgMCA+Pgpl bmRvYmoKMyAwIG9iago8PCAvVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMKL0tpZHMgWzYgMCBSCjE2IDAgUgpdCi9Db3Vu dCAyCi9SZXNvdXJjZXMgPDwKL1Byb2NTZXQgNCAwIFIKL0ZvbnQgPDwgCi9GMSA4IDAgUgovRjIg OSAwIFIKPj4KL1hPYmplY3QgPDwgCi9JMSAxMiAwIFIKL0kyIDE1IDAgUgovSTMgMjAgMCBSCi9J NCAyMyAwIFIKPj4KPj4KL01lZGlhQm94IFswLjAwMCAwLjAwMCA2MTIuMDAwIDc5Mi4wMDBdCiA+ PgplbmRvYmoKNCAwIG9iagpbL1BERiAvVGV4dCAvSW1hZ2VDIF0KZW5kb2JqCjUgMCBvYmoKPDwK L0NyZWF0b3IgKERPTVBERikKL0NyZWF0aW9uRGF0ZSAoRDoyMDEzMDgyMzAyMDA0NCswMCcwMCcp Ci9Nb2REYXRlIChEOjIwMTMwODIzMDIwMDQ0KzAwJzAwJykKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjYgMCBvYmoKPDwg L1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UKL1BhcmVudCAzIDAgUgovQW5ub3RzIFsgMTAgMCBSIDEzIDAgUiBdCi9Db250 ZW50cyA3IDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKNyAwIG9iago8PCAvRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZQovTGVu Z3RoIDI3OCA+PgpzdHJlYW0KeJyFkb1Ow0AQhHs/xZRQsNm9/2tRAnJEA1wXpUBJSIOFIAWvz9ox FwMKyNLJmtuZb3evYWJmTM/3fXNdYJIljhbRGnIxoWwxuzEQT4zyDKwuSlvuFpdrlCUWpfmd83Cr YvT4AGOJFbDWn21Tg00mYYsO1iTKJlXlBY/fnYaMH90uE0tAZNVSVrMPhnJyVfnL3NcGzkNtCG50

Comment: what are the header lines doing in their ? look at the swift mail examples. your mixing sending email with with forcing a file download.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the partial message (`ontent-Type: ...`), I'm guessing that the output buffer filled up and was automatically flushed, leaving only the output *after* the flush to be assigned to `$message`.

There are also two extra blank lines between `--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>` and `Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ...` which could cause trouble.

Relying on output buffering to construct a string is both error prone and completely unnecessary. It is **much** better to use PHP's [HEREDOC syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) instead:

```
  $message = <<<MSG
--PHP-mixed-$random_hash
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-$random_hash"

--PHP-alt-$random_hash
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message<br /><br />


--PHP-alt-$random_hash--

--PHP-mixed-$random_hash
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="$filename"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$filename"

$attachment;
--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--

MSG;

$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Note that the line endings in a mail must be CRLF (eg. \r\n). If the above doesn't work, you may have to construct a string with explicit line endings:

```
$message = "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n"
         . "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-$random_hash\"\r\n"
         . "\r\n"
         /* ... */
         . $attachment
         . "\r\n--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--"
         . "\r\n";
```

See PHP's [mail() manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for some further details.